# Produce output for values greater than n and ignore the rest in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to display only lines with second value greater than 1000. The original JQ program I am using to display everything is:

```sh
jq -r '.[] | [.name, .size] | join(",")' file.json
```

This gives me:

```
name1,1024
name2,300
name3,512
```

If I select values only greater than 1000:

```
jq -r '.[] | [.name, .size | select(. > 1000)] | join(",")' file.json
```

then I am getting:

```
name1,1024
name2
name3
```

How can I discard lines with size less than 1000?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select objects, not fields.

```
.[] | select(.size > 1000) | [.name, .size] | join(",")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0jQ_nl38Iu)</sup>